# Retrieving data from a closed workbook without being prompted to select the workbook file?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works great at retrieving the data from the closed workbook in the file path. However, I am prompted to select the actual file every loop. How do I avoid having to select the file manually?   thank you

```
Sub BrandSpecificSettings()

Dim i As Integer
Dim inputs As Worksheet
Dim brand As String

Set inputs = Worksheets("inputs")

brand = inputs.Range("k2").Value

For i = 1 To 27
    If inputs.Range("a" & i).Value = "" Then
        i = i + 1
    Else:
        inputs.Range("b" & i).Value = "='J:\Wassner Enterprises\brand inventory sheets\[" & brand & ".xlsm]settings'!b" & i
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Side note: remove the `:` after `Else`.

Comment: Why don't you have VBA open the file before the loop and then close it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

With **GetObject** you can retrieve information from a workbook without the need to be displayed.

```
Sub BrandSpecificSettings()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim inputs As Worksheet: Set inputs = Worksheets("inputs")
    Dim brand As String: brand = inputs.Range("k2").Value
    
    Dim Filename As String: Filename = "J:\Wassner Enterprises\brand inventory sheets\" & brand & ".xlsm"
    
    Dim wbTemp As Workbook: Set wbTemp = GetObject(Filename)
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet: Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets("Settings")
    
    For i = 1 To 27
        If inputs.Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
            i = i + 1
        Else:
            inputs.Range("B" & i).Value = wsTemp.Range("B" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Closes the workbook
    wbTemp.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```